# How can I share video on Pinterest

Tags: share, pinterest

I want to share a video using pinterest share . But not found any api for share video using pinterest.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to share video as shown here:
http://www.pinterest.com/videos/

However, as of now (March 2014) Pinterest API does not support this feature:
https://developers.pinterest.com/api_request/

Comment: But on you tube there is button to share video using pinterest.

Comment: Yes Pinterest supports sharing of videos on YouTube and a couple other popular video sharing websites, they won't let you share just any video from anywhere however.